Reward bounty if an answer is given but there is no solution to the stated problem
Am I supposed/obligated to reward a bounty (and/or set the accepted answer) if my problem has not been solved, but the question is answered by the problem not being solvable?
For Example

Q: I need to do X but using only Y and not Z


A: Sadly, there is no way of doing this. You will have to use Z.


You are never obligated to accept an answer or reward a bounty, any user who asks for either through a comment, should have their comment immediately flagged. A bounty once offered cannot be refunded, and if whatever reason an answer becomes eligible, will receive a portion of the bounty automatically if a different answer isn’t selected before the bounty ends.
